# Android Import Overlap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rhino

I'm using Mozilla's Rhino in my Android project. However, my version of Java has a copy of this library in the JDK. Because of that, I received the error:

```
06-22 17:59:01.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1150): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context
```

I put the same exact jar in the "libs" folder for my project, but I had no luck in overriding the original library. Basically I want to tell eclipse to stop pointing toward the JDK's version of Rhino and point toward mine. Is there anyway I can do this without deleting the files inside the JDK's jar files?

EDIT:

[image: Highlighting the import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context, then going to Declarations->Project]
[image: The import comes from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes]

As you can see from the two images, when I highlight the import, the eclipse says that the import is being referenced from the jdk, not my .jar file.

EDIT:
My build path.
[image: Java Build Path/Libraries in eclipse]

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of your Java Build Path properties? select the Libraries tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Android project does not use the JDK's classes. And there are no `sun.*` in the Android SDK (and, hopefully, in any of Android itself).

[This blog post](https://vec.io/posts/embed-javascript-in-android-java-code-with-rhino) would seem to indicate that the standard `js.jar` should work out of the box.

If you are recompiling Rhino for some reason, you should be compiling against an `android.jar` in an Android library project, not against the JDK's class library.

Furthermore, you are specifically referencing JDK internal classes. Rhino itself does not have `sun.*` classes, AFAICT, based on what I am seeing on Mozilla's site and [the Rhino project repo](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino).

Comment: Fixed. Once I saw that indeed none of them had sun.* classes, I fixed the packages.